# How to restore the deleted code files with using git

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I was developing a web application. I also used Git with it. For approximately one month, I didn't push to Github. During my attempt to push updated code today, I found a file with a memory size of approximately 500 MB. It shows the error that the file is too large for Github. Therefore, I tried removing that file from the commit in the staging area. I then added that file to .gitignore. Following that, I tried **git reset** and **git trash**. However, they did not work. Using the command git add and then git commit with the updated commit. The file is still listed there. I found the command **git reset --hard 'origin/main'** on StackOverflow. The command reverted the previous commit, and I lost all my code. The git logs do not show any updated commits. Would it be possible to find that code there?

I added the screenshot from **git reflog**.
[image: git reflog]

When I run the below command, I need the files before Update after forecasting. It shows the error attached in the screenshot.

> git checkout 950362c -b restored_branch

[image: aftetr git checkout]

Comment: Can you share the first couple of lines from `git reflog`?

Comment: 6a49195 (HEAD -> main, origin/main) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to origin/main
002d069 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD
002d069 HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD
002d069 HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to HEAD
002d069 HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to HEAD
002d069 HEAD@{5}: reset: moving to HEAD
002d069 HEAD@{6}: reset: moving to HEAD~
b3156da HEAD@{7}: reset: moving to HEAD
b3156da HEAD@{8}: reset: moving to HEAD
b3156da HEAD@{9}: commit: Updated after forecasting 3
002d069 HEAD@{10}: commit: Updated after forecasting 2

Comment: 950362c HEAD@{11}: commit: Updated after forecasting
6a49195 (HEAD -> main, origin/main) HEAD@{12}: commit: after company-vitals api
b7469cb HEAD@{13}: commit: Data before giving to ali
19e8c07 HEAD@{14}: commit: More code after data api
f3e0665 HEAD@{15}: commit: After market close cron jb
05a41ef HEAD@{16}: commit: Last changes before giving to ALI
8eca90c HEAD@{17}: commit: After profile cronjob
01987aa HEAD@{18}: commit: After Sentiment and Quote Page
2048939 HEAD@{19}: reset: moving to origin/main
858c809 HEAD@{20}: reset: moving to HEAD

Comment: 858c809 HEAD@{21}: commit: After sentiment analysis and quote page
abb6f56 HEAD@{22}: reset: moving to HEAD
abb6f56 HEAD@{23}: commit: After Quote Page
2048939 HEAD@{24}: commit: Added the one to one serializers to update API
d3daa97 HEAD@{25}: commit: after authentication
9386737 HEAD@{26}: Branch: renamed refs/heads/master to refs/heads/main
9386737 HEAD@{28}: reset: moving to HEAD
9386737 HEAD@{29}: reset: moving to HEAD
9386737 HEAD@{30}: commit: After sorting and filters
57f51d6 HEAD@{31}: reset: moving to HEAD
57f51d6 HEAD@{32}: commit (initial): After sorting and filters

Comment: Here are 32 lines, I pasted in three comments. Please check

Comment: @Mureinik I added the screenshot also in the question.

Answer (score 3):

`git reflog` shows a kind of history of the actions you performed in git. Each linehas the commit hash and what you did there.

The first line shows that you had commit `6a49195` and performed a reset on it. Assuming git hasn't GCed yet (and if you didn't do anything else since it shouldn't have), this commit should still exist, even though its no longer associated with any branch, and you should be able to check it out:

```
git checkout 6a49195 -b restored_branch
```

Comment: Just a quick question, my first commit, which I needed now is 950362c. But you added the id which is for old commit. Does the command you mention will help me to restore the code.

Comment: I need the data before "950362c HEAD@{11}: commit: Updated after forecasting" this commit. So what is the possible way?

Comment: @HuzaifaZahoor Looks like you need that state of commit `b7469cb`. You can check out from there instead.

Comment: I have added the screenshot when I run the command for checkout. It is showing another error. So please check it out. One more thing I need the 950362c state of commit.

Comment: @HuzaifaZahoor as the error message says, you have local (uncommitted) changes so you cannot checkout. One way to solve this is to stash them (`git stash save`) before performing the `git checkout`.

Comment: So, I run this command again with right commit ID after running git stash save.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. Now I have all my code. But now, I'm unable to push it on github. Like when I push, it pushed nothing. Just show that everything is uptodate on remote origin.

Comment: @HuzaifaZahoor if you're sure you want to overwrite the branch you have on GitHub, you can add the `--force` flag to your push: `git push --force origin <target_branch>`

Comment: I have now code in restored+branch, when I push the code to the github with --force flag. It still shows the same error message like the file is too big. How can I remove that file from commit. I tried to delete that from that path using CLI. Then I run git rm <file_path>, git reset HEAD <file_path> etc. But still when I push to github. The file error is still same. How can I reset the commit and then again repeat the whole process. Thanks for your help.

Comment: git filter-branch --index-filter  "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch <file_path>" --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

I used this command. It helps me to solve my issue. Thanks